# How do I start Instruments to profile a MonoTouch application?

Tags: xamarin.ios, instruments

I'm writing an application for the iPhone in MonoTouch, and I have some performance problems I would like to investigate. I can see from resources on the net, that I should use Instruments for this. I looked up the [documentation](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Profiling_MonoTouch_applications_with_Instruments) from Xamarin on how to profile my app with Instruments, but this documentation says I should start Instruments via the Terminal. But when I try to run the command, it says Instruments is not found. I tried looking at the /Developer folder, and there's no Instruments there.

As far as I understand, Instruments is now integrated with XCode 4 (Which is the version I have installed) and so I can't launch Instruments on it's own.
It seems Instruments will only launch when XCode has a project loaded, but how can I open my project in XCode when it's a MonoTouch project?

It seems other people can get it working, as there's alot of questions on SO regarding MonoTouch and Instruments and how to analyze the data. But I haven't been able to find any that tells me how to actually start Instruments and profile my MonoTouch app.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Xcode 4.2, try this from a terminal:

```
open /Developer/Applications/Instruments.app
```

If you have Xcode 4.3, you can open Instruments from inside Xcode's menu: Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Instruments

Comment: +1 Thank you so much! I can't believe I overlooked that menu item. I did look through them all, but I must have missed the "XCode" menu item itself. Doh! :-)